# PhoneGap Android Web Service response using jQuery is NOT coming

Tags: android, web-services, cordova

We are developing a small contact store application using PhoneGap framework. We have a webservice to perform operations for creating, updating, reading and deleting a contact. We are using the following code to make a SOAP request to create a contact. We are using jQuery and jquery mobile http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.js. The following code is working with iPhone simulator and iPhone. But we are not even getting the response on Android and Android emulator. We greatly appreciate your help.

```
var settings = {requestType:"soap1.1",
       error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       throw XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
     }};
 var oBuffer = new Array();
 settings.requestType = "soap1.1";
 settings.methodType = "POST";
 settings.contentType = "text/xml";
 settings.url = "http://example.com/checkdatpriceservice.asmx";
 settings.dataType = "text/xml";
 settings.nameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";
 settings.methodName = "VerifyUser";

 oBuffer.push('<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">');
 oBuffer.push("<soap:Body>");
  oBuffer.push('<VerifyUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">');
    oBuffer.push('<email_id>abcd@example.com</email_id>');
    oBuffer.push('<password>user123</password>');
  oBuffer.push("</VerifyUser>");
   oBuffer.push("</soap:Body>");
 oBuffer.push("</soap:Envelope>");
 settings.requestData = oBuffer.join("");
 alert("requestData:" + settings.requestData);
 $.ajax({
   type: settings.methodType,
   cache: false,
   url: settings.url,
   data: settings.requestData,
   contentType: settings.contentType,
   dataType: settings.dataType,
   error: function(status){ alert("An error occurred in processing your request");},
   success: function(data, testStatus){
     alert('data = ' + data);
     $('#testp').html(data);
   },
   beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){
     if (settings.requestType == "soap1.1" || settings.requestType== "soap1.2")
       XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",settings.nameSpace + settings.methodName);
     XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",settings.requestData.length);
     XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Looks to me like it should work. If you run `adb logcat` to take a peek at the logs on your device/emulator, do you see any errors? Try doing `adb logcat | grep "Web"` to get only output related to the browser/PhoneGap.

Comment: I have a similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176985/soap-query-with-jquery-phonegap-always-fail-on-android 

Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue.
When I am trying to run the index.html on eclipse, everything works fine.
But when trying to run on the simulator, there is no response data . 
I have found that even the length of the response data is ZERO.

It would be great if someone can post the solution or a small example of how phonegap can run a web service which takes a soap xml  request and gives the response in xml.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the logcat but I did not find any "Web" word, when the button which runs the web service is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using settings.dataType = "xml"  (instead of "text/xml").

"text/xml" is not a valid dataType for $.ajax call thus the intelligent guess may have run in your iphone and not in your android sim.