# Soap query with jQuery / Phonegap always fail on Android

Tags: jquery, android, soap, jquery-mobile, cordova

I developed an iPhone/Android app with jQuery mobile & Phonegap (now Cordova). This app use different services with no problem. One of this services is a Soap one so i use the jsSOAPClient (jquery.jqSOAPClient.js) for jQuery in order to request the service. I have no problem at all from an iOS device but the query always fail on Android.

In jsSOAPClient the request looks like that :

```
        function getResponse(xData, status) {
            if(!!callback) {
                SOAPClient.Status = xData.status;
                SOAPClient.ResponseText = xData.responseText;
                SOAPClient.ResponseXML = xData.responseXML;
                callback(xData.responseXML);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: SOAPClient.Proxy,
             dataType: "xml",
             processData: false,
             data: content,
             complete: getResponse,
             beforeSend: function(req) {
                req.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST");
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", SOAPClient.ContentLength);
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", SOAPClient.ContentType + "; charset=\"" + SOAPClient.CharSet + "\"");
                req.setRequestHeader("SOAPServer", SOAPClient.SOAPServer);
                req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapReq.Action);
             }
        });
```

The "getResponse" "status" value is "error" and the "SOAPClient.Status" (equal to "xData.status") value is "0".

The server seems to not receive request at all...

I repeat that the same code with the same request datas have results on iOS.

Thanks for help.

/ EDIT *****/
I tried to comment the line :

```
//type: "POST",
```

it seems to work, i mean i have a 200 status code in this case even if i have a parse error due to the unexpected response format.

Comment: I have this same problem, hence, my offering the bounty.  I have some additional information.  I asked the network admin to use wireshark to watch the packets between the phone and the server.  Here is what he observed:

Comment: "TLSv1 appears to be aborting with an Encrypted Alert that is acknowledge by the server.  There are FIN packets followed by a reset (RST).  This looks like a handshake that is failing at the client at the tail end of the negotiation process."    I looked a the message and saw this: "TLSv1 Record Layer: Encrypted Alert; Content Type: Alert (21); Version TLS 1.0 (0x0301); Length 24; Alert Message: Encrypted Alert".  Just like the OP, I am only having a problem on Android.

Comment: Here are two links of people seeing same thing we are in wireshark:http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8334 and http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-05?_done=%2Fgroup%2Fandroid-security-discuss%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fmonth%2F2010-05%3F&

Comment: Just to make sure: your proxy is running on the same domain as your JS?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug in Android 2.x where setting the
"Content-length" header causes the problem you describe. It looks like
the bug has been fixed in Android 4.0.3. So try your code unmodified
in the 4.0.3 emulator and it should work then come back to 2.x and
remove the Content-length header to see if it works as well.